# List images from WDS remotely

Tags: image, powershell, wds

I want to get list of Images from a WDS Server (Windows Deployment Services) remotely.

I'm using the PowerShell command `Get-WdsInstallImage` and it needs the highest privileges.

I'm tried the below commands, but they don't work:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName "<computer name>" -Authentication Kerberos -Credential $(Get-Credential) -ScriptBlock {Get-WdsInstallImage}

Invoke-Command -ComputerName "<computer name>" -ScriptBlock {Start-Process PowerShell.exe Get-WdsInstallImage -verb runAs}
```

Comment: Maybe using the `-CimSession` works better for you: _Runs the cmdlet in a remote session or on a remote computer. Enter a computer name or a session object, such as the output of a New-CimSession or Get-CimSession cmdlet. The default is the current session on the local computer._  
`$mySession = New-CimSession -ComputerName wdsname -Credential $(Get-Credential) -Authentication Kerberos; Get-WdsInstallImage -CimSession $mySession`

Comment: `Get-WdsInstallImage' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet`  , probably because  i don't have WDS role on myhost  and i don't wan't do that.

Comment: You made a typo in the first command: `-ceredential` should be `-Credential`.

Comment: ok, corrected , but in my code it was good

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$w=Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "<target system>" -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Class "MSFT_WdsBootImage" -EnableAllPrivileges -List
$x=$w.Get()
$x.cmdletOutput

$y=Get-WmiObject -ComputerName "<target system>" -Namespace "root\CIMV2" -Class "MSFT_WdsInstallImage" -EnableAllPrivileges -List
$z=$y.Get()
$z.cmdletOutput
```

Don't forget to use `-Credentials` if necessary.